# JavaFX GUI release background task

Tags: javafx, blocking

I have a simple JavaFX window which display a message. When I call JavaFX application to display something it works, but the caller is blocked while the FX window is open. I want to display window but the background process should not be blocked. How can I do it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you update your answer with an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do some background stuff and not freez you GUI, you have to use JavaFX Service.
Everything is explain  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html)